# Enable does not work jQuery

Tags: jquery, disabled-input

I try to disable/enable a textbox depending on the input other textbox has.
When `role` textbox's input is `_teacher_`, the the `subject` textbox is `enable`. Otherwise, `disabled`.

Problem is it does not enable it back when the input is `teacher`

```
function check(event) {
    if ($('#role').val().toLowerCase() == "teacher")
            $("#subject").removeAttr("disabled"); 
    else
        $("#subject").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
}
```

**view.tpl**

```
<input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="role" onkeypress="check(event)" placeholder="Teacher/HR" name="role"/>
<br/>
<input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="subject" placeholder="Subject(only if Teacher) " name="subject"/>
<br/>
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to give a definitive answer. Please show more of your code, including the HTML for the elements and how you've bound the check function to the form.

Comment: @Juhana I just added the html part

Comment: Use the `onkeyup` event instead (or better yet, bind the event with jQuery, not inline.)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("#subject").prop("disabled", false);` to enable and `$("#subject").prop("disabled", true);` to disable the element

Comment: That is equivalent to adding and removing an attribute.

Comment: same thing happens :( it does get disabled but remains like that even if the input in "teacher" :(

Comment: @Juhana No, it's not.

Comment: @Juhana What makes it a particular case? `disabled` is a property, using `prop` is more reliable than setting/removing the attribute.

Comment: @Vohuman I don't think we use the same definition for the word "particular". In any case, feel free to show a version of the OP's code that works with `.prop()` but doesn't work with `.attr()`.

Comment: @Juhana Well, the point wasn't whether it fixes the OP's problem or not. Using `prop` is not equivalent to "adding and removing an attribute", there is no guarantee that browser will update the corresponding property.  There are many related questions on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: @Vohuman Ok, I agree, but I never said (or meant to say) that `.prop()` and adding/removing *any* attribute is *always* equivalent. I was commenting why *this specific* answer is wrong, because (implicitly) in *this* case they are equivalent.